# Does Shaybani discuss the topic of male circumcision in any of his writings?

Tags: hanafi, circumcision

As how the question states "Does Shaybani discuss the topic of male circumcision in any of his works?" and if he does, what does he say about it? That it is Sunnah or obligatory? Please give exact quotes and references to those discussions if he does mention it.